# What is the equivalent tag for bean:define in struts2.5?

Tags: struts2

```
<bean:define 
  id="beanObj" 
  name="<%=Constants.Header_details%>" 
  scope="session" 
  type="com.domain.HeaderDetails" 
/>
```

The above tag is used in struts1 code. I am migrating to struts2.

Comment: There is no direct equivalent, but `<s:set>` is the closest. It's rare you'd actually need or want it; `<bean:define>` mixes back-end concerns with the view layer. Unrelated, but it's a good idea to at least read your question after posting it, because without code formatting, much of it disappeared.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Could you please explain me how exactly this bean define tag works in struts1?

Comment: It puts a bean of the specified type into the specified session under the specified name...

Comment: Thankyou Dave:)